# automation script on mongo db giving binary error

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-query, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

Trying to run the script on mongo db to check utlization getting error: cannot execute binary file, any suggestions.

```
[bp09@zlv172 ~]$ sh disk.sh 
./kubectl config use-context agef

./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash  -- df -h

/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126
```

When tried with:

```
./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash -- file /usr/bin/df
```

bash: file: No such file or directory command terminated with exit code 127

```
./kubectl config use-context agef

./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash  -- df -h

/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126



[bp09@zlv172 ~]$ ./kubectl config use-context agef
Switched to context "agef".

[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl get pods
NAME              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongoagef-0   2/2       Running   0          20d
mongoagef-1   2/2       Running   0          24d
mongoagef-2   2/2       Running   0          20d


[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash
bash-4.2$ df -h /data/db
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/de/map/data_vg-shared_vol2  3.5T  1.8T  501G  75% /data/db
```

but when running with : -

```
[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash -- df -h
/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126


[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash -- file /usr/bin/df -h
bash: file: No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 127


[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash -- file /bin/df -h
bash: file: No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 127
```

when checked with locate df command below is the output:-
[bp09@zlv172 ~]$ locate df

```
/bin/df


[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash
```

bash-4.2$ cd /usr/bin
bash-4.2$ ls -lrth|grep -i df

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  99K Oct 30  2018 df
```

Comment: can you try running `./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash  -- file /usr/bin/df` and share its o/p ?

Comment: getting the output: ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash  -- file /usr/bin/df  
 bash: file: No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 127

Comment: ok, so the container does not have `file` command so the output is not useful. Thanks. This seems like your `df` executable is not built proper or overwritten. to validate the same, I asked for `file` command result, however due to its unavailability just guessing.

Comment: HI, any suggestion how to get he output.

Comment: when checked df file location: ./kubectl config use-context agef
[bp09@zlv172 ~]$ locate df|head -10
/bin/df

[bp09@zlv172 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash

bash-4.2$ pwd
/usr/bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  99K Oct 30  2018 df

Comment: any suggestion  how to run the query to get disk utlization;  ./kubectl exec -it mongoagef-2 -c mongo bash -- file /usr/bin/df

Comment: issue is not reproducible to me, I used `mongo` image. Are you sure you are using `mongo` image ? see below command where I spawned a pod with `--image mongo` and `df -h` is working fine.

Comment: `psk@psk-VirtualBox:~$ k exec -it mongo --  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          32G   13G   18G  42% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5        32G   13G   18G  42% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
psk@psk-VirtualBox:~$
`

Comment: are you sure your is built right if you are making your own? I am sure something is wrong with your pod image

Comment: Yes using the correct mong image, added output from command line.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no solution to the problem as its not reproducible in my environment. may be you can try `k exec -it mongo -c mongo -- /bin/sh  -c df` to see if it helps. even if it works, I wont be able to explain why it worked :)

Comment: Yes it works thanks, i manage to run the script and schedule it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that, `df` command was working when you login to container and run the command, but not when run using `exec`. Alternatively you Call the shell and then call the command you need. Eg:

```
kubectl exec -it mongo -c mongo -- /bin/sh  -c df
```

> -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are
> arguments after  the  com‐
> mand_string,  the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.
> The assignment to $0
> sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

k exec -it mongo -c mongo -- /bin/sh  -c df this works fine.